# How to calculated the difference between levels values based in clusterization result?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose we have a pandas dataframe with two columns:

```
Col1  Col2         
  0    15         
  0    20         
  0    30         
  1    40         
  1    45         
  0    50     
  0    55         
  2    60         
  2    70
```

I need to calculated this based in col2 in other dataframe or array:

```
Col1  Col2     
 0     30-15=15    
 1     45-40=5     
 0     55-50=5     
 2     70-60=10
```

Finally the result:

```
Col1  Col2     
  0    15    
  1    5     
  0    5     
  2    10
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what the algorithm for that calculation is?

Comment: Each label in column 1 determines a layer(the column 2 is the Depth) so I need to know the thickness of each layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.ptp` (peak to peak)

```
df.groupby(df.Col1.ne(df.Col1.shift()).cumsum()).Col2.apply(np.ptp)
```

---

```
Col1  Col2     
  0    15    
  1    5     
  0    5     
  2    10
```

Comment: @EdwinMald You can also do `df.groupby([df.Col1.ne(df.Col1.shift()).cumsum(), 'Col1']).Col2.apply(np.ptp)` . Did it work for you?